# optarg is always empty on gcc 4.8.3

Tags: c, gcc

I've been developing my code on gcc 4.7.2, but I also need it to run on a machine with 4.8.3.
On gcc 4.7.2 (Debian [Crunchbang Linux]), I get the following output:

```
#./executable -f fakefile -h hostname

inputFile: fakefile
Setting inputFile to optarg: fakefile.
hostname: hostname
Setting hostname to optarg: hostname.
```

On gcc 4.8.3 (Fedora):

```
inputFile: 
Setting inputFile to optarg: <garbage>.
hostname: <garbage>
Setting hostname to optarg: hostname.
Segmentation fault
```

Code is below for reference.  I should mention that I don't actually know if the difference in the gcc versions is what is causing the issue: It just seems most likely to me.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting garbage + segfault on 4.8.3, and not on 4.7.1?  Thanks for the help.

```
opterr = 0;
int c;
while (( c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:h:c")) != -1)
{
    switch ( c )
    {
        case 'c':
            LOG("Setting compression to TRUE.\n");
            compression = TRUE;
            break;
        case 'f':
            LOG("inputFile: %s", optarg);
            if ( optarg != NULL && strlen(optarg) < sizeof( inputFile ) )
            {
                strcpy( inputFile, optarg);
                LOG("Setting inputFile to optarg: %s.", inputFile);
            }
            break;
        case 'h':
            LOG("hostname: %s", optarg);
            if ( optarg != NULL && strlen(optarg) < sizeof( hostname ) )
            {
                strcpy( hostname, optarg);
                LOG("Setting hostname to optarg: %s.", hostname);
            }
            break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option %c.\n", optopt);
            print_help();

            teardown();
            return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for me with both GCC 4.7 and 4.9 on GNU/Linux.  Do any non-trivial programs work if compiled with your GCC 4.8?

Comment: What are `hostname`, and `inputFile`? Post a short, complete, compilable example that demonstrates this behavior. Leave out all the completely irrelevant `LOG()` and `print_help()` and `teardown()` stuff.